# Any gotchas if I name a ruby class/instance method 'return'?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am writing a class that represents a pool of IPC connections that are going to be used by other objects.  I was thinking of naming the class/instance methods `borrow` and `return` (e.g., `Pool.borrow / pool_instance.borrow` and `Pool.return(connection) / pool_instance.return(connection)`).

Are there any gotchas that I need to be aware of, considering that return is perhaps a reserved word?

Comment: Doesn't interpreter say about syntax error???

Comment: naming a method `return` is not a syntax error (had to try it myself to be sure)

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should[TM]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In similar cases I have used the terms "CheckOut" and "CheckIn" instead of "Borrow" and "Return," you might see how those terms feel to you.

I think the fact that you're worried about it is enough reason not to do it. Especially when the alternative is to simply pick another name.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that, in general, naming methods as keywords is a bad practice, regardless of whether or not it's syntactically ok.  At best it might confuse people using or maintaining your code (perhaps even syntax highlighters in editors); at worst it could cause unexpected behavior at runtime.

Best to avoid it and pick a slightly different name, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any keywords that you can't use as method names; as long as you don't leave out the receiver, it's always clear to the parser that it's a method name.

I agree that you should use caution here.